# Clean way to handle Enum::XX_CustomBase

Tags: c++, qt, enums

Qt defines it's last enum as `PREFIX_CustomBase` to allow framework-users to extend this enum with custom values. E.g.

```
enum StandardPixmap {
    ...
    SP_MediaSeekForward,
    SP_MediaSeekBackward,
    SP_MediaVolume,
    SP_MediaVolumeMuted,
    // do not add any values below/greater than this
    SP_CustomBase = 0xf0000000
};
```

Further more, there are callback methods (slots or virtual methods) which are called with these values, e.g.

```
QIcon MyCustomStyle::GetStandardPixmap( StandardPixmap ePixmap )
{
    switch( ePixmap )
    {
        case SP_NewPixmap:   return "/home/user/new_pixmap.svg";
        case SP_OtherPixmap: return "/home/user/other_pixmap.svg";
    }
}
```

I can use this mechanism in two ways:

1. Using `#define` to define my new custom value
   e.g. `#define SP_NewPixmap (QStyle::SP_CustomBase+2)`
2. Using my own `enum` - but have to cast every time
   e.g. `enum MyPixmap { SP_NewPixmap = QStyle::SP_CustomBase+1; }`

Using the `#define` is C-style and thus in C++ not the right choice. Creating a separate enum will force me, to cast every time to Qt's enum type - also ugly.

Is there another way, with is a bit smarter?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Qt, but presumably you have access to the header file containing `StandardPixmap` ?

Comment: The header file of the StandardPixmap is part of the framework/library - thus I have no access. This is why they added this custom_base

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick that might help you but probably is a bit ugly as well and does not work if you are overriding a method: Using ints for your methods.

The relation between ints and enums works like this:

```
int pixmap = QStyle::SP_MediaSeekForward; // compiles
pixmap = SP_NewPixmap;                    // compiles
QStyle::StandardPixmap ePixmap = pixmap;  // does not compile
```

Therefore you could change the parameter of that method to an int (in case of a slot, not in case of a virtual method override obviously) and do:

```
QIcon MyCustomStyle::GetStandardPixmap( int ePixmap ) { /* ... */ }
```

and then call

```
QIcon icon1 = GetStandardPixmap( QStyle::SP_MediaSeekForward );
QIcon icon2 = GetStandardPixmap( SP_NewPixmap );
```

Comment: I need this overriding - maybe not for the Pixmaps, but for all other elements... e.g. [drawPrimitive(PE_MyElement)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstyle.html#drawPrimitive)

Comment: I would probably go for the defines then in your case